# Signin with claims, but user is still unauthorized to access controller with Authorze attribute .net 6.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a .net 6.0 mvc projects that receives a token after logging in through an external API. I want to signin to the context of the web application with claims. But still the the user isn't authorized.

Heres my program.cs code:

```
var connectionString = "test";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/User/Denied");
        });

var app = builder.Build();
```

Here is my UserController.login code:

```
  public class UserController : Controller
    {  
        public IActionResult Login()
        {                                                
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("Token", "sdflksjflskdjfldskjfdlskf"),//this is the token that I received my api that i want to store.
                    new Claim("Email", "youssef@youssef.nl")
                }, "Token");
              
            
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);            
            SignIn(principal, new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),   
            });
                                                
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But when I use the Authorize attribute on my controller, the user seems not authorized:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }       
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to the offcial doc about [Claims-Based Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-claims-checks) and check if you add claims checks correctly.

Comment: Thank you @YiyiYou for your answer. I had to add attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] to get it working. But User.Claims.Count = 0 and User.Identity.Name = null. Do you know why this is?